# Edit AWS SNS message sent to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

In my pipeline I have an event notification on an S3 bucket which triggers an SNS topic. That SNS topic in turn has a lambda function subscribed to it. I need the SNS topic to send a hard coded message body to the lambda because it get's used in that function.
Since the SNS topic publishes the message automatically when the S3 event notification is set off I am wondering if and how I can edit the message that gets sent to lambda?

To be clear: I want the same message sent every time. The goal is for lambda to get a variable which is only dependent on which topic the lambda was triggered from.

Currently I am building this through the UI but will eventually code it in terraform for production.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, because the integration between S3 <> SNS is basically to send events from S3 to SNS, you can't change the message. So if you set an event on ObjectCreated, it will send: "An object was created" and the same for ObjectRemoved and etc. But you can easily ignore it in your lambda, the SNS will trigger the lambda but you don't need to read what's inside the message.

Comment: So while we can't change the message S3 sends to SNS, is there a way I can pre-define a message that gets sent from SNS to lambda every time the topic publishes? Or is it limited to "forwarding" the message from the S3 event notification?

Answer (score 0):

When Amazon SNS triggers an AWS Lambda function, the information it sends includes SNS `TopicArn`.

You could use that ARN to determine which SNS Topic triggered the Lambda function, and therefore which action it should process.

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:{{{accountId}}}:ExampleTopic",
      "Sns": {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "95df01b4-ee98-5cb9-9903-4c221d41eb5e",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:ExampleTopic",
        "Subject": "example subject",
        "Message": "example message",
        "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Signature": "EXAMPLE",
        "SigningCertUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "MessageAttributes": {
          "Test": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "TestString"
          },
          "TestBinary": {
            "Type": "Binary",
            "Value": "TestBinary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The lambda function is kicking off glue jobs. The glue job depends on the topic the lambda is triggered by. Instead of coding the mapping from topic to glue function within the lambda, I would prefer to pass the glue job name in the message from SNS. That way an new topic and glue job don't require changes to the lambda function. My idea was to set the Message: "example message" to Message: "<glue job name>". Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having Amazon S3 send a message to Amazon SNS directly, you *might* be able to configure an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** that triggers on object creation and sends a **Constant** as part of the message to Amazon SNS, like this:

[image: Amazon CloudWatch Events rule]

If large files are being uploaded, you might also need to trigger it on `CompleteMultipartUpload`.\

You could also have the rule trigger the AWS Lambda function *directly* (without going via Amazon SNS), depending upon your use-case. A Constant can also be specified for this.

Comment: The constant looks like a promising option. In order for this to work I would have to be able to define different constants depending on the file which triggers the event (similar to s3 event notification prefix and suffix). I did not see an option to get that granular. Does it exist somewhere?

Comment: That's starting to sound like a use-case for logic in an AWS Lambda function. You _might_ be able to use the [Input Transformer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html), which can shift-around data in JSON but it doesn't seem to offer any logic (eg `if` statements).